# Unit converting design pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, loose-coupling, unit-conversion

I need to make conversions between units, each unit has 2 parts, its name and an integer, the integer part can be either positive or negative. I need my `Unit` class to have dependency injection and be loosely  coupled. For example if I need to add something in the future, I don't want to have to change my other classes that are using this class.

There should be also a `Convert()` method in my unit class to convert between units. I took a look at these links:

- [Type Conversion in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98bbex99.aspx)
- [Pattern for Creating a Simple and Efficient Value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040999/pattern-for-creating-a-simple-and-efficient-value-type)

But these seem loosely coupled.

Please let me know the recommended design pattern for this problem,

Comment: Neither one of your links talk about unit conversion (Type conversion is completely different).  What dependencies will your Unit class have?

Comment: I am looking for solution we implements units with small change, we can extend the Unit class without big changes to other classes.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a custom attribute for methods that specifies the unit a method can convert to and from. Then your converter function can extract the unit from the items being converted and use reflection to find those classes with convert methods that convert to/from those units.

You do need a core unit of measurement that you use for your convert to/from methods. E.g. pick metric and then all conversions convert to/from metric to/from a second unit. Then to go from unit A to unit B, you convert from A to metric, then convert to B from metric, with A and B converters picked using reflection.

Of course, since you don't provide too much detail on your request, it is hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do so this is a wild guess "design". :)

Comment: Thank you ,For Example , now I have gram and kilo gram, but In future may be I need to have pound.I need the conversion of these units together  , Do you have any example of source code? I don't like to go through each unit and define new conversion.

Comment: Somebody put strategy design pattern here and then removed from here . PLease let me know any design pattern