# Custom value type, EF Code First and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, routes

In our WebApi project we use EF CodeFirst approach. Also we use 2 types of databases: SQL Server and MySQL. All tables have the field `ID`, but in SQL Server database this field has `int` data type, in MySQL database this field is `char(36)` and contains `GUID`.

To solve the problem I created a custom value type like `IdType` and changed all model classes to use that type insted `int`:

```
public class Document
{
  public IdType ID { get; set; }
  public string DocumentNm { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Then I configured the DbContext (e.g for SQL Server)

```
modelBuilder.Properties<IdType>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("int"));
```

...and changed repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
  IQueryable<T> GetAll();
  T GetById(IdType id);
  ...
}
```

After that, when I try to go to e.g. `http://localhost:7081/api/Document`, it gives me an error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type
>   WebUI.Controllers.API.DocumentController\r\nGetById on type
>   WebUI.Controllers.API.DocumentController

I use default settings of routing. Here is `[HttpGet]` methods from DocumentController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
public HttpResponseMessage GetById(IdType id) { ... }
```

How can I solve the problem? Could this be the cause of incorrect implementation of `IdType`?

P.S. I created IdType for int values as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040999/pattern-for-creating-a-simple-and-efficient-value-type). if I have to add more informations, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

DocumentController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetById(IdType id)
{
    var entity = repository.GetById(id);

    if (entity == null)
    {                
       return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("No {0} with ID = {1}", GenericTypeName, id););
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
 }
```

My repository:

```
 public virtual T GetById(IdType id)
 {
    return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
 }
 public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
 {
   return entities = context.Set<T>();
 }
```

Comment: Could you add IdType type and GetById method?

Comment: @Chase I've updated the question and added GetById method. IdType has more code and you can see it in [GitHub](https://github.com/Marusyk/SmartVillageOnline/blob/IdType/Domain/Concrete/IdType.cs)

Comment: Okay, so current code is fine, can you add repository.GetById?

Comment: @Chase Yes, of cource. I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it not implemented yet in current version of Entity Framework

And as mentioned in [task on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242#issuecomment-158569520)

> we're currently planning to work on lighting this feature up after our
>   initial RTM of EF7.

Comment: I'll update the answer if there is some movement on this